# Debugging a Major Data Binding Memory Leak in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following data bindings set up which cause a huge memory leak:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridReflections" Width="auto" MaxWidth="1570" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,0,240,0">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ColourSet}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bearing (PLL)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding BearingPLL, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Bearing (°)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding BearingDegrees, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Subtended (PLL)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding SubtendPLL, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Subtended (°)" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding SubtendDegrees}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Range" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding Range, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Intensity" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding Intensity, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Width="*" MaxWidth="221" Binding="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Which is linked in the code behind as such:

```
private void UpdateUserInterface()
{
    if (ReflectionsReported != null)
        ReflectionsReported.Clear();
    ReflectionList reflectionDatas;
    for (ReflectionCount = 0; ReflectionCount < SmallestArray(); ReflectionCount++)
    {
        reflectionDatas = new(ReflectionCount);
        ReflectionsReported.Add(reflectionDatas);
    }
    labelMarkers.Content = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Marker][0];
    labelReflections.Content = dataGridReflections.Items.Count;
}
```

And the ReflectionsList is defined as:

```
public ReflectionList(int i) : base()
{
    ColourSet = ReflectionsUC.normal;
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
    ReflectionData reflr = new()
    {
        BearingPLL = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Bearing][i],
        BearingDegrees = Math.Round((decimal)Convert.ToInt32(Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Bearing][i]) / 65536 * 360, 3),
        SubtendPLL = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Subtend][i],
        SubtendDegrees = Math.Round((decimal)Convert.ToInt32(Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Subtend][i]) / 65536 * 360, 3),
        Intensity = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Intensity][i],
        Range = Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Range][i],
        Time = DateTime.Parse(Reflections.Revolution[(int)Reflections.Data.Time][0]).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    };
```

With each value defined as:

```
public class ReflectionData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _bearingPLL;
    private decimal _bearingDeg;
    private string _subtendPLL;
    private decimal _subtendDeg;
    private string _intensity;
    private string _range;
    private string _time;
    public string BearingPLL { get { return _bearingPLL; } set { if (_bearingPLL != value) { _bearingPLL = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public decimal BearingDegrees { get { return _bearingDeg; } set { if (_bearingDeg != value) { _bearingDeg = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string SubtendPLL { get { return _subtendPLL; } set { if (_subtendPLL != value) { _subtendPLL = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public decimal SubtendDegrees { get { return _subtendDeg; } set { if (_subtendDeg != value) { _subtendDeg = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string Intensity { get { return _intensity; } set { if (_intensity != value) { _intensity = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string Range { get { return _range; } set { if (_range != value) { _range = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public string Time { get { return _time; } set { if (_time != value) { _time = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The update user interface method gets triggered every time the Reflections.Revolution gets filled with new data. If I remove all user interface elements and just have the data coming in there is no memory leak, but as soon as I allow the update user interface method to be ran I get up to 12 gigabytes over an hour!
Is there a better / easier way for me to do this with minimal processing / memory usage, understanding I do have a lot of data here which is updating once every 0.125 seconds.

Comment: You might also consider posting this question to Code Review, since you're asking for help with improving performance.

Comment: That is very weird code. Why do you have reflectionDatas declared outside the loop. What's it doing there?

Comment: Is your datagrid read only? So you could bind onetime?

Comment: @devlincarnate, it's not suited to [codereview.se], at is clearly isn't _working as intended_ until the memory leak is fixed.

Comment: @Andy reflectionDatas was moved out to allow me to see if it has any affect on the memory and block individual parts
Admitedly this code has changed a lot to try and stop the leak, so I feel myself it might not be as readable / anywhere near as optimised as it should

Comment: Setting it as readonly does not seem to help

Comment: @TobySpeight : I don't agree with your logic (because any code that isn't optimal isn't working as intended), but ok.

Comment: @devlincarnate, there's a specific exception for code that scales poorly to large inputs, but is otherwise correct - this question _might_ just scrape through on that, but it's up to that site's community to judge.  Full details are in [CR's help page](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and you can always ask [their Meta](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you're unsure.

Comment: @TobySpeight looks like it might
the code works really well, there is just a memory leak... if you can call that working really well?

Comment: Read only AND onetime on the bindings was my suggestion.

Comment: Time for some tough love. If you want to fix this you should build a mvp. You've just dumped pieces of code and markup. I don't find all those datagrid columns very interesting. Most of reflectiondata is a bit meh. What about the datacontext. Where does Reflections come from. You don't show us.

Comment: @Andy yeah so I have readonly and one time set, sorry!

Comment: Will look into MVP, I totally get here that I have dumped a load of code and hoped someone may spot something stupid I am doing. Reflections are taken from a dictionary, which is populated by 0.125s of data from a serial port

Comment: And where do you bind the data grid to the items source? The collection it is displaying?

Comment: Are you using a few static classes? Singletons? They can stick around.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question, but not a stupid idea: have you ran the code with a memory profiler so you can see what is causing the leak? Which classes are staying around when they should be gone?

Leaks occur when the garbage collector cannot clean up an object because it is still being referenced.  Without a memory profiler I would look at any code which creates new objects or attaches event handlers as those will be the ones which are most likely to get stuck in memory. You have a class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, it is possible that the event handler is not being removed when the binding is.

This would be a lot easier to diagnose if you had a working sample, of course this is not always easy to do, so you can do some tricks if you don't have access to a memory profiler such as implementing IDisposable or Finalizers to see if your classes are ever being disposed of. You can put a timer in your classes that prints their hash or construction time to the console every minute that they exist. You can also force a garbage collection to be done using GC.Collect()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-5.0

My advice is to download a memory profiler and use a trial version. JetBrains has one with a 5 day full feature trial.